# How to get access to user information by if statement?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, fgets

I am trying to give access to a user for his information by asking him his name and then showing him the details. So how could I do that? Whenever I name, it gives me no access, means I am not allowed to get access. I tried and search a lot but didn't find the right answer.

```
int list_view(char *name, size_t namesize){
    printf("For person details, please enter the person name and id card number: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    if(!fgets(name, namesize, stdin)){
      printf("No access");
      return 0;
     }
    FILE * fr;
    int one_by_one;
    fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "r");
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("\nHere is your "); 
        while((one_by_one = fgetc(fr)) != EOF && one_by_one != '\n'){
          printf("%c",one_by_one); /*  display on screen*/
        }
    }
    fclose(fr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My man page says `fgets(s, size, stream)` "returns `s` on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read." So it's good to check for failure, but that doesn't seem to relate to "access".

Comment: How to make that if statement working? This is my question.

Comment: That depends on what you want to test there.

Comment: What do you mean with "Whenever I type true or false name"?

Comment: Whenever fgets is successful (a name was entered), the program will print 'no access'.  Maybe you should first test the result of fgets() to see is a name was entererd, then chenckthe name in a separate if statement.

Comment: I see that's the second time you ask this question, so there is clearly something blocking your perception about this situation, the condition `if(fgets(name, namesize, stdin))` will only be false if there is an error while reading or if the end of file occurs, these two situations don't often happen when reading strings from stdin. Other than that, anything you enter will be succefully read and the condition will evaluate to true, so  "no access".

Comment: I have update my question, it means name but the true and false name is the name which is present text file or not.

Comment: You will need to store the name, then read the file and print the info only if the name is present in the file, if you post the contents of the file it's easier to find a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file has the names and the details of those names in the same line, creating a simple search by name in the file and comparing it to the inputed name. Assuming a line size no larger than 199 characters excluding the name which would be no larger than 99 characters and a single word, here's a sample of a possible implementation:

[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/SupportiveSilentConversion)

```
int list_view(char *name, size_t namesize)
{
    char line[200];
    char name2[100];

    printf("For person details, please enter the person name and id card number: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");

    if (!fgets(name, namesize, stdin)){//read name from stdin
        perror("Error while reading!");
        return 0;
    }
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0'; //remove \n

    FILE *fr;

    if(!(fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "r"))){ //always check fopen for errors
      perror("Unable to open file");
      return 0;
    }

    while(fscanf(fr, "%99s", name2) == 1) //search name in the file
    {
        if(!strcmp(name2, name)){ //the name is found print the rest of the line
            if(fscanf(fr, "%199[^\n]", line) == 1){ 
                printf("%s", line);
                fclose(fr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you look at my previous answer to the same question I said you must write

```
if(!fgets(dob, dobsize, stdin))
```

see the '!' character in the if

Comment: I put this but it didn't work. I commented but you didn't respond.

Comment: Instead of just answering, why you people are giving down options. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: what do you mean 'it didnt work'. What you need to do is to get your code working bit by bit, first, prompt the user for something and then just echo it back , get that working before doing any file IO